# I couldn't ask this question for a long time because it kept prompting “It looks like your post is mostly code, please add some more details”

Tags: support, asking-questions, question-quality, quality-filter

I was trying to ask a question. [I finally succeeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54989797/why-cant-i-insert-nodes-after-deleting-nodes-from-my-linked-list), but only because I kept smashing on the "Post Question" button. The system kept telling me:

> It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details

Was this a bug, or was the heuristic right?

I'll admit it was not a great question, but I think I should have been allowed to post it. Does my question contain enough details? Is there something that I need to know to improve how I ask questions?

Comment: I've cleaned up the formatting a little (but you may want to look at the code indentation still), and left a comment pointing to the [formatting help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and our [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) help pages.

Comment: Are you *really* expecting us to agree with "*I'll admit it was not a great question, but I think I should have been allowed to post it.*"? We want *good questions*; the filter stopping your question was the filter doing exactly the job it was meant to.

Comment: "Is there something that I need to know to improve how I ask questions?" -- Have you gone through the [help] and in particular the [ask]? And if so, do you have any specific questions about any points that confuse you?

Comment: Doesn't look like you debugged it. [Debugging your code](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging) allows you to follow the actual execution of your logic. It often reveals in a moment exactly what's wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Considering your question has been closed and deleted, I don't think you provided enough information.  I can't see the specific question, but from the error, some advice stands out: *"Please add some more details"*.

We want questions that are more than just pasted code.  We can't read your mind at all, so unless you tell us what's going wrong, there isn't going to be much we can do.  Giving us those details allows us to help you.

Some general advice: If you're getting an error that doesn't allow you to post a question, take it to heart, and follow it.  Trying to bypass the error won't end well for anybody; your question will get down voted and closed, likely deleted, and you won't get the help you want.  Curators will be annoyed because you didn't ask a good question, and actively routed around our protections in place, and will be less willing to help you for that reason alone.

Help us help you.  Give us more than just code to go off of.  Listen to what the system is telling you.  Follow the advice you get.  The more you invest in your question, the better the chance you'll get the help you want.